# Is it good practice to have $_GET or $_POST inside a class function?

Tags: php, web-services

I have a php class, RegistrationController,

```
<?php
 class RegistrationController  extends ParentController {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'We are inside RegistrationController';
    }

    public function register() {
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        echo "<li> We will register soon, $name </li>";
    }
 }
?>
```

I am accessing the register method via URL like this, [FYI, I am using RewriteEngine in .htaccess]

```
http://localhost:8888/Service/RegistrationController/register?name=Owl
```

---

#### Question

Now, everything works fine, I just need to make sure my queries have those `?name=Owl` variables set when I request some computation.

The web service will **not** be accessible from Web Browser it's just a trivial service I want to made for my Mobile application. The application will be calling this URL as it is without any change except the details (var).

So, is it okay to $_GET or $_POST inside class's function? Is it scalable or maintainable?

---

#### Additional Info

I am calling the methods of different controllers in very generic manner, so In my Bottstrap I am just calling this function which lets me call any controller's method with few lines.

```
private function handleMethodCallOn($controller, $url) {
        //check if the URL has specified any method to call
        if(isset($url[1])) {//URL has been exploded earlier to get content
            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}();//HERE I am calling any function
            } else {
                $error = new error_404();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would use a wrapper class for this like in symfony 1.x: `sfWebRequest` (even if it won't be accessible from a web browser, who guarantees it?) It will help to maintain your code in a long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly viable to use post and get inside a class method. What jumps out at experienced devs about your code is more likely to be 2 things: 
1. lack of input validation
2. dumping user input directly into your page's output (one can only hope that you aren't doing similar things on the way into the database).

If you are not interested in using a framework, you can do these things manually. 
However, there are myriad solid PHP frameworks which can bootstrap a RESTful request for you, abstracting it into an object, rich with input validation and the like.

Comment: +1, Haha, The code in question is just conceptual abstraction of real code, it just addressing my dilemma. However of course I have making sure the validation aspects. But nice to hear about strong frameworks, Could you please drop few names in your answer. Tha would be great. Thanks

Comment: I'll give a strong positive nod to Zend, and a strong negative nod to CodeIgniter (I've used each for at least 12 months on large enterprise projects). I have heard that there are many other impressive frameworks out there.

Comment: @ctrahey it might be beneficial to list reasons why you think CodeIgniter is a bad choice and why Zend is a good choice. Kohana is another one i'd say is good.. I've been dealing with FuelPHP here lately as well.. Its Ruby like console is pretty nice to work with.

Comment: For fear of getting too involved in a framework debate, I'll spin it to only positive: Zend is enterprise savvy, and will motivate you to do things the right way, even if it seems complicated at first; and CI will help you develop a rapid prototype, delivering a demonstrable concept sooner and with less thought required.

Answer (score 0):

It is "ok", in the sense that it will work, but it should not be done.

It's an easy fix. Instead add the name as an argument to the register method.

simplified version...

```
class RegistrationController  extends ParentController {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'We are inside RegistrationController';
    }

    public function register( $name ) {
        echo "<li> We will register soon, $name </li>";
    }
}

$registration_controller->register( $_GET['name'] )
```

This makes the code 100% transparent.  No secrets happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi, yes that's a viable solution as well, but check my additional info in question where I have shown how I am handing to method call. It's more generic from my Bootstrap class. I did not wanted too much mess so made this generic function which lets me call any method in any controller and then I thought I will handle those get and post params. But I guess I am wrong :(